# Use react-router without a DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was wondering if it is possible to use react-router outside of the DOM. My goal is to use react-router along with react-blessed to create a terminal application.

I saw that I can shim my own history object, but I'm not very familiar with how that would look. I also saw that I can use history/lib/createMemoryHash, but it seems that it calls the location update too quickly, before react has had a chance to setup.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes - https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createMemoryHistory` is indeed the correct approach to take - it emulates a browser history in-memory.

You can take a look at how some of the React Router tests for elements like `<Link>`s are set up to see it in action: [Link-test.js#L281-L312](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/c5aae35ffed8caabbe9a19da48012434bbff55a0/modules/__tests__/Link-test.js#L281-L312).

I'm not sure what you mean by "calls the location update too quickly, though". The idea would be that you start on a particular location, then transition from there as needed.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is correct. I found my "location update too quickly" cause. There is a bug in react-blessed. Something to do with not using batched updates.